# Cannot access MVC WebApp from server itself when Windows Authentication is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed a MVC 5 web application on a cloud hosted server. It uses Windows authentication. The company itself uses a different domain than the servers in the cloud use.

For example. The company uses xycom as domain and the cloud computers use xycloudcom as domain.

The xycloudcom servers have access to the AD controller of the xycom domain.

Now I installed an application on the cloud server. It has only Windows Authentication enabled and all works fine when accessing from a computer and account in xycom domain.

The only issue is that I am not able to open the website from the server itself. It opens a dialog asking me for my credentials. If I enter them (my xycom account) I get a 401 Unauthorized.

If I enable Anonymous authentication I can open the web site. So it's not a DNS issue.

Can someone help to solve this issue since I need to trigger an action by a console application in ScheduledTasks using a web request.

Server is Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: Whats the identity in Advanced Settings in Application Pool settings.

Comment: The Identity is a service account that I got in the xycom domain (to be able to access that Active Directoy. Here it is "xycom\Srv_mywebapp")

Comment: Loopback? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to open the site from the server, if that server is not on the same domain.

The integrated windows authentication would work only if there is a trust between your Cloud VM's domain and the xycom comain.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But server is in xycloudcom domain. All users are using it from xycom domain. Why can't I open it from the same domain where the server is? Or even from exactly the same machine?